# How to properly align side-by-side blocks in a container

Tags: html, css, inline, children

I have a div with display block and in it I have others in inline-block. This is what I have.

[display:inline-block case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzmr4.png)

When I put div inside the first in display: block, with float left, I have this:

[display:block with floating case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N174D.png)

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 50%; /*Of its parent*/
}

#container > div {
    display: block;
    width: 22%;
    padding: 5px 1.2%;
    float: left;
 }

 /* or

 #container > div {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 22%;
     padding: 5px 1.2%;
 }

 or

 #container > div {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 22%;
     padding: 5px 1.2%;
     float: left;
 }

 */
```

Please, can someone tells me what it is wrong and help to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you put some code here? This way we can help you in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`5px 1.2%` and `22%` won't work really well, try

```
#container > div {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 5px 1%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
 }
```

```css
#container>div {
  display: block;
  width: 23%;
  padding: 5px 1%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok.This is what I want to do. I think the problème is the height. I have added the height and it seems to works very well. But I don't want to put height for my div , height must be auto. Is there a way to make it work properly without specifying the height?

Comment: @Cutis do you have a min height or max height you want? or % of the screen size?

Comment: I have tried min-height , this is what I have http://prntscr.com/f7zg6h

Comment: Ok, I find what is wrong. I have another div in inline-block without contents which break my style: http://prntscr.com/f80lul.   And when I use display: block, float: left with min-height, I get this: http://prntscr.com/f80moc . I don't know why. But I fix my issue using display: inline-block, without min-height and floating. I will put it Fixed! Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: flex`. Floats tend to create issues. Flex looks to fix some of those issues. A great guide can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/